# Are UIKit target-actioin selectors always invoked on the main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, uikit

I have a weird crash in CoreData `fetchRequest` that can only be explained by it being executed outside of the main thread.

I do `addTarget` on my `UITextEdit` and when the selector method gets invoked, do some data retrieval.
I was under assumption that that will always happen in the main UI thread. Should this be the case? In the crash report I received I can see this

```
Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001abe4d198 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001abe4c60c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001abff73b4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 148 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001abff23e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001abff1c34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001ac334bcc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228 (NSRunLoop.m:374)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001ac334aac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:421)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b01c6160 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152 (UIEventFetcher.m:736)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001ac4639d0 __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001abd8fd98 _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001abd9374c thread_start + 8
```

Which looks like the main thread. But the call stack of the crash is in a different one

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ac02ebbc __CFStringChangeSizeMultiple + 300 (CFString.c:1063)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ac0298f0 __CFStringAppendBytes + 616 (CFString.c:1129)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ac0298f0 __CFStringAppendBytes + 616 (CFString.c:1129)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ac01b570 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 12116 (CFString.c:0)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ac01bb10 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 152 (CFString.c:1919)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001ac33ca38 -[NSString initWithFormat:] + 56 (NSString.m:1891)
6   CoreData                        0x00000001b0a7d5b0 +[_PFRoutines valueForProcessArgument:] + 128 (_PFRoutines.m:1481)
7   CoreData                        0x00000001b0c0a8a8 _newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_ST + 448 (NSSQLCore_Functions.m:4539)
8   CoreData                        0x00000001b0bfd0d4 _executeFetchRequest + 68 (NSSQLCore_Functions.m:4952)
9   CoreData                        0x00000001b098ebb8 -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext executeRequestCore:] + 40 (NSSQLFetchRequestContext.m:494)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIKit` has its own internal event fetch thread (“Thread 1” usually - the one you saw crash).  With CoreData, it’s best to use [`NSManagedObjectContext.perform(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506578-perform) on your main thread context.  This will guarantee any fetch requests performed inside the block occur on the context’s thread.

Answer (score 0):

Thread 0 (your second snippet) is actually the main thread. I can tell because threads that are not the main thread start with a call to `thread_start` or something similar.

So you are fetching and crashing on the main thread. Just based on your logs, I would guess that the crash occurs because of a formatted string you're creating close to the place where you fetch. A likely culprit is the formatted strings that you need to create an `NSPredicate`.